# Docker don't have permission on this server

Tags: apache, docker, server

I have a dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.
I don't understand why i don't have the permission ...

I have also a index.php in my public folder

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN apt-get update && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  php:
    build: './image/'
    volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www/html/
    ports:
    - '30000:80'

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - '40000:8080'

  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=meetup
```

Folders:

```
meetup
  app
  bin
  get_started
  image
    dockerfile
  public
     index.php
  src
  templates
  docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: What command are you running and what error are you getting?

Comment: I'm doing this command: docker-compose up -d and when I try to access the port 20000 the error is:You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: * port 30000 sorry

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, it simply looks like the root directory of the Apache does not contain `index.php`.

You should do one of these:

- Either move the `index.php` from your `public` folder to your `src` folder
- Or, change the mount in the `docker-compose` from `./src:/var/www/html` to `./public:/var/www/html` (in any case, the trailing slash is not needed).

Comment: I change to ./public:/var/www/html but know i have a 500 error (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Well, that is a different problem. Try with a simple index.php, one that just prints "hello", and remove things from the docker compose until you get the Apache to work (I was able to make it work without problems, same setup I described).